# Sort matrix A according to the ordering of matrix B

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting

I want to create a new array equal to A (or sort array A), but in the order of B.

I am only deleting the elements of array A when not in Array B, but they are not staying in Array A, in the order of Array B.

**My array A is:**

```
$ array_A [0] ['name'] = Robson;

$ array A [0] ['value'] = ROB;
 
$ array_A [1] ['name'] = Morticia;

$ array A [1] ['value'] = MORT;
```

**My array B is:**

```
$ array_B [0] = "Morticia";
 
$ array_B [1] = "Robson";
```

I want to create a new array equal to A (or sort array A), but in the order of B.

**Expected result:**

```
$array_A[0]['name'] = Morticia; 

$array_A[0]['value'] = MORT;

$array_A[1]['name'] = Robson; 

$array_A[1]['value'] = ROB;
```

**My code today is:**

```
if(!empty($array_A)){
    if (!empty($obj->allnames)){
        $array_B = explode(",", $obj->allnames); 
        **// You have to sort array_A by array_B
    }
    $x=0;
    foreach ($array_A as $value) {
        if (!empty($array_B)){
            if (!in_array($value->f_name,$array_B)){
                unset($array_A[$x]);
            }
        }
        $x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: why tagged with `Javascript`?

Comment: Because I code php and javascript, any algorithm can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you could use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom comparison function finding the keys from `$array_B` using [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) by the value of `$array_A` and then compare them.

```
$array_A[0]['name'] = "Robson";
$array_A[0]['value'] = "ROB";
$array_A[1]['name'] = "Morticia";
$array_A[1]['value'] = "MORT";

$array_B[0] = "Morticia";
$array_B[1] = "Robson";


usort($array_A, function($a, $b) use ($array_B) {
    return array_search($a['name'], $array_B) > array_search($b['name'], $array_B);
});
print_r($array_A);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Morticia
            [value] => MORT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Robson
            [value] => ROB
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/MJ4TG)

In php 7 you can also use the `<=>` spaceship operator

```
usort($array_A, function($a, $b) use ($array_B) {
    return array_search($a['name'], $array_B) <=> array_search($b['name'], $array_B);
});
```